# Cython runtime error "size changed, may indiciate binary incompatibility"

Tags: python, cython

I am writing custom Cython modules on a Windows system. Running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` works fine and the modules are compiled without error. I have a Cython module A that cimports another Cython module B:

```
from prolothar_rule_mining.models.event_flow_graph.alignment.alignment cimport Alignment
```

During runtime, this produces the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: prolothar_rule_mining.models.event_flow_graph.alignment.alignment.Alignment size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 24 from C header, got 16 from PyObject
```

Do you have any idea, how to fix this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide [mre]. At least how Alignment-class is defined and how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error. The runtime error message was quite misleading.

My Alignment class looked basically like this:

```
cdef class Alignment
   cdef list __moves
```

Removing the double underscores solved the issue:

```
cdef class Alignment
   cdef list moves
```

The underscores came from the old pure python version of this class.

Comment: I doubt very much, this was the reason. If you change `moves` to `__moves` back,  rebuild everything  you won't see the error. Probably **rebuilding everything** was the solution to your problems.

Comment: You are right, changing `moves` back to `__moves` did not lead to an error. However, I tried to rebuild everything multiple times and even deleted all compiled files and I still got the error until I removed the underscores. I have absolutely no clue why it failed and why it works now.